# client.ts:112 TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, asynchronous

I created a file that will connect to mongodb and retrieve data. I tested this file on its own and it worked perfectly, but after trying to access it within one of my components I get the error specified within the title. This is the full error for more clarification of the issue:

```
client.ts:112 TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_types.js (mongo_types.ts:402:74)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=9e080f79:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js (abstract_cursor.ts:16:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=9e080f79:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/aggregation_cursor.js (aggregation_cursor.ts:11:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=9e080f79:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js (collection.ts:6:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=9e080f79:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js (change_stream.ts:4:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=9e080f79:18:50)
warnFailedFetch @ client.ts:112
fetchUpdate @ client.ts:453
await in fetchUpdate (async)
(anonymous) @ client.ts:159
handleMessage @ client.ts:157
(anonymous) @ client.ts:90
Show 5 more frames
client.ts:114 [hmr] Failed to reload /src/components/Category.tsx. This could be due to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)
```

I tried to update my dependencies but that didn't help and in fact made everything worse. I used dpdm to check for circular dependencies across all of my relevant files and that came up with no errors. I tried putting the function declarations within my component, within a useEffect and the same issue came up. This also causes another problem, when the code is commented out the website starts perfectly but otherwise a blank screen will pop up if I run npm run dev. These are my files:

### Category. tsx

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import '../styles/category.css'
import { useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { drawerContext } from '../utils/DrawerContext';
import { useSnapshot } from 'valtio/react';
import { store } from '../utils/store';
import ReactPaginate, { ReactPaginateProps }  from 'react-paginate'
import WestIcon from '@mui/icons-material/West';
import EastIcon from '@mui/icons-material/East';
import  {main}  from '../FetchItemData';


   export const Category = () => {


    const {category} = useParams();
    const {gender} = useParams();
    
  
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    let lowerCategory = category!.toLowerCase();

    const {SearchBarContainerOpen, DrawerOpen, setIsSearchBarContainerOpen, setDrawerOpen } = useContext(drawerContext);
    console.log(lowerCategory)
    console.log(gender)
    
    const snapshot = useSnapshot(store);

    //useEffect(() => {
     // main(gender!, category!);
   // })
   
    const products = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Product 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Product 2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Product 3' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Product 4' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Product 5' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Product 6' },
      { id: 7, name: 'Product 1' },
      { id: 8, name: 'Product 2' },
      { id: 9, name: 'Product 3' },
      { id: 10, name: 'Product 4' },
      { id: 11, name: 'Product 5' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Product 6' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Product 6' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Product 6' },
    ];

    const handlePageChange: ReactPaginateProps['onPageChange'] = (selectedPage) => {
      setCurrentPage(selectedPage.selected);
    };

  
  return (
    <div className = "category-body">
      <Navbar iconColor='black' backgroundColor='white' z_index='1' />
      <main className = "main" style = {snapshot.SearchBar ? { filter: "blur(10px)" } : snapshot.DrawerOpen ? { filter: "blur(10px)" } : undefined}>
        <div className="grid-layout">
        {products.map((product) => (
          
          <div key={product.id} className="grid-item">
            <div className = "product-card">
              <div className = "product-card-image">
                <img src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1003/3354/files/125SP232000F_ESSENTIALS_TEE_JET_BLACK_1_900x.jpg?v=1685911035">
                </img>
              </div>
              <div className = "product-card-item-description">
                <h3>Product Name</h3>
                <h4 className = "">Website</h4>
                <span>Price</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        ))}
        </div>
        <div className = "pagination-container">
          <ReactPaginate 
            previousLabel={<WestIcon className = "icon"/>}
            nextLabel={<EastIcon className = "icon"/>} 
            pageCount={8}  
            breakLabel = {'...'}
            marginPagesDisplayed={3}
            previousClassName='previous' 
            nextClassName='next'
            pageClassName = 'page'
            containerClassName='pagination'
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
            activeClassName='active'
            />
          </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my category component which needs to fetch data to populate the component with the proper data according to the parameters: gender, category. However, this is where the error occurs.

### FetchItemData.ts

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";


export async function main(gender:string, category: string){
  /**
   * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
   * See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node/ for more details
   */
  const uri = "mongodb+srv://(removed for this purpose)@cluster0.ww8cwxm.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";


  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  try {
      // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
      await client.connect();

      // Make the appropriate DB calls
      await  listDatabases(client, gender, category);

  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
  } finally {
      await client.close();
  }
}


export async function listDatabases(client: MongoClient, gender:string, category:string){
  let collection = gender == "Him" ? "him-items" : "her-items"
  let cursor = client.db("E-commerce").collection(collection).find({category: category}).limit(1)
  while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
    const document = await cursor.next();
    console.log(document);
  }

};
```

And this is the function which fetches data from mongoDB. Btw dont worry about some of the code its mostly used to test for functionality at the moment.

Someone please help. I've been on this issue for a day now and I feel like I've looked everywhere for an answer